# pass form value in PUG as a paramater in onclick function

Tags: node.js, forms, pug

I am trying to pass a value from a form to use as a parameter in a function in a onclick button. But im not sure how to get the value.

This hardcoded example works:

`button.btn.btn-glider(onclick=helpers.subscribe("name@gmail.com")) Download`

And I have tried the following to get the value from the form

`button.btn.btn-glider(onclick=helpers.subscribe(('fieldEmail').value)) Download`

`button.btn.btn-glider(onclick=helpers.subscribe(document.getElementById('fieldEmail').value)) Download`

```
mixin Report
    form
        .modal#ReportModal
            .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-centered.modal-dialog-scrollable(role='document')
                        .modal-content
                            .modal-header
                                .modal-title
                        
                                button.close(type="button" data-dismiss="modal") &times;
                            .modal-body
                                div.loading.d-none
                                    .spinner#searchSpinner
                                        .bounce1
                                        .bounce2
                                        .bounce3
                                div.form
                                    p.highlight.text-center.small Enter your name and email to download 
                                    div.mb-3
                                        input.form-control(aria-label="Name" id="fieldName" maxlength="200" name="cm-name" placeholder="Name")
                                    div.mb-3
                                        input.form-control.js-cm-email-input.qa-input-email(autocomplete="Email" aria-label="Email" id="fieldEmail" maxlength="200" name="cm-ydkykyi-ydkykyi" required="" type="email" placeholder="Email")
                            .modal-footer

                                button.btn.btn-glider(onclick=helpers.subscribe("name@gmail.com") Download
```

and this is the function im calling

````
function subscribe (email) {

};```
````

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Pug question or a node question since it appears to be all happening client-side. You'll get more responses if you ask the question showing the compiled HTML instead of Pug, as well as showing the actual JS function. If you can remove the extraneous code (like the spinner) to create a [mcve] that would improve the question as well.